# Wamp phpMyAdmin error #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, root

This is quite common problem and I found a lot of tutorials to help me solve it, although, there is one additional problem with my case...

This is my config settings in config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
```

When I try to log in via wamp main page, the error shows:

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

AND this same is when I try to acces MyAdmin by CONSOLE!

No matter what I type as password or just press enter, it shows me this same error, and because of that i cant 'flush priviliges'.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that these credentials are correct?

Comment: Which part confused you?

Answer (score 14):

**Step 1: Open your MySQL console.**

**Step 2: Enter the Provided Command Lines**

$`use mysql;`
$`UPDATE mysql.user SET password="PASSWORD("YourPassword") WHERE user="root";`
$`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
$`exit;`

**Step 3: Open and edit your config.inc.php file located in your local server files**

1. Go to My Computer > C Drive > ( Your Local Server Folder,
   WAMP/MAMP/XAMPP ) > APPS > PHPMYADMIN > config.inc.php
2. Using a text editor, such as Notepad++, open your config.inc.php file.
3. Find this line of code: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; // MySQL password
4. Change ['password'] = ''; --to--> ['password'] = 'YourPassword'; with the new chosen password you created from Step 2.
5. Click Save

**Step 4: Go to phpmyadmin**
 go to `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/`.

Answer (score 7):

Change the line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Restart and you will be asked for the password the next access to the phpmyadmin page

Comment: I change the file C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\config.inc.php, this line $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'new pass'; and worked!

Answer (score 4):

Did you add a password to the MySQL 'root' userid?

If not, by default it comes without a password. So use

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

and remove this its a defunct parameter since phpMyAdmon 3.2.0

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try username = root and password is blank.

Answer (score 0):

go to `control panel > administrative tool> service >`

then you will find a list of items , navigate to `MYSQL`

right click on its `properties`  , in `general tab`  start type `make it automatic`

then `apply / save`

and finally `restart all services in wamp`

Answer (score 0):

after changing the root password you must first enter the following in mysql console:

**FLUSH PRIVILEGES;**

before the changes will take effect

Do this by openening a terminal/command console and navigating to your mysql.exe example:
*C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysql -u YOURUSERNAMEHERE -p*

If you have fiddled with your root account and can no longer access it see the following link for resetting your root account:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

After this it should work fine as per your **config.inc.php** file

Answer (score -2):

On the MySQL error page, where two pink coloured error panels are appeared, you can find a small button at right side there. click on it.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Perhaps some detail and a screen shot would help...

Comment: Downvoted because @debika never followed up to clarify and the answer as it stands makes no sense