# Error #1045 when accessing db from another computer on another network

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, vps

I'm trying to do a MySQL db on a vps computer and reach it from my pc. From the vps (with Windows remote access) I can log in and do what I want, but when I try to log in from my computer (which is on another network) it gives me error #1045.

The ports are forwarded and everything works fine except logging in. (I can see the login panel)

Any solutions for this?

Comment: See: [Wamp phpMyAdmin error #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20131652/55075)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at db server, from what location is able to get acces on server, is there % permision in location, or is it specified different