# How to connect django project to mysql database if the mysql database reside in wamp server?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I googgled alot and see many solutions, but none of them worked for me. I have a project in django and also an app as well. now, I want  a connection to mysql database that reside in wamp server in order to interact (sending data or getting data) to database through my app.I also installed MYSQLDB for python. and I have done neccessary things in settings.py file.following is content of settings.py regradding of database

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME':   'flask',
        'USERNAME':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'',
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing the database? (E.g by running migrations...) Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: yes, I tried but it returns an error "access denied" however I add an user with all previliages.

Answer (score 0):

In this [link](https://ericeastwood.com/blog/3/django-setup-for-wamp%20combined%20with%20httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html), you can find information about Django setup for WAMP. Also you may need to add port number to the database settings which is 3306 as default.

Comment: before I post the question I also check that link what every I do an error comes up by the name of "access denied" and also want ask to connect django to database I must use wsgi or mod_python? is there any other concise way for connecting to database through django

Comment: No you do not need to do anything more. Are you sure your user informations are correct, for example does your user have password? [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131652/wamp-phpmyadmin-error-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost) are some solutions about access denied problem on WAMP.